# unable to start minikube on windows10

Tags: minikube

I am trying to install minikube on Windows10 Home but am getting this error. Why?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --driver=hyperv
* minikube v1.11.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.19041 Build 19041
* Using the hyperv driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 60 [running]:
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.hypervAvailable(0xc00008cff0, 0xc0002cdd00)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/powershell.go:64 +0x105
github.com/docker/machine/drivers/hyperv.(*Driver).PreCreateCheck(0xc000439ec0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /go/pkg/mod/github.com/machine-drivers/machine@v0.7.1-0.20200323212942-41eb826190d8/drivers/hyperv/hyperv.go:171 +0x3b
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.(*LocalClient).Create(0xc000043540, 0xc000439f20, 0x0, 0x0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/client.go:221 +0x3f5
k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost.func2(0x1e80ea0, 0xc000043540, 0xc000439f20, 0xc0006c0540, 0xc0004c6af0)
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:184 +0x42
created by k8s.io/minikube/pkg/minikube/machine.timedCreateHost
        /app/pkg/minikube/machine/start.go:183 +0x10e

C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube status
E0627 09:15:44.982608   38068 status.go:132] The "minikube" host does not exist!
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Nonexistent
kubelet: Nonexistent
apiserver: Nonexistent
kubeconfig: Nonexistent


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Hyper-V is disabled. Run PowerShell and execute `$hyperv.State -eq "Enabled"` command
2. Disable Hyper-V (if it is running) by executing following command in Powershell(in admin mode) `Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All`. Reboot your PC
3. Run **CMD** as an administrator
4. Try to execute `minikube delete` if it fails the try to remove '.minikube' folder manually from C:\Users{your username}
5. Try to execute `minikube start`
6. Execute `minikube status` command to verify it is running

Hope it will help